# Attributes to a subclass of pandas.DataFrame disappear after pickle

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass, pandas

I am trying to add attributes to a subclass of pandas.DataFrame and they disappear after pickling and unpickling:

```
import cPickle
import pandas as pd

class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.bar = 1

myc = MyClass()
with open('myc.pickle', 'wb')as myfile:
    cPickle.dump(myc,myfile)
with open('myc.pickle', 'rb')as myfile:
    b = cPickle.load(myfile)
print b.bar
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_df.py", line 14, in <module>
print b.bar
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1771, in __getattr__
(type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Any idea how I can add attributes safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to subclassing. Pandas objects' attributes do not serialize.

You can read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pydata/9Qimqt4ekvQ) for a discussion and a workaround. The topic has resurfaced again in [this other recent thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pydata/2ORknH_70co).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I'll check these links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @property decorator to do something similar:

```
class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foo = 1


    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 1
```

`MyClass.foo` will not be available after pickling, but `MyClass.bar` will be there (as of now, read only).

Comment: How would this work dynamically, though, unless foo will always be 1?