# Get the name of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes

How do I get the name of a DataFrame and print it as a string?

Example:

`boston` (var name assigned to a csv file)

```
import pandas as pd
boston = pd.read_csv('boston.csv')

print('The winner is team A based on the %s table.' % boston)
```

Comment: Do you mean variable name?

Comment: It's worth reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python), and the comments and links therein.

Answer (score 90):

You can name the dataframe with the following, and then call the name wherever you like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.ones([4,4]) )
df.name = 'Ones'

print df.name
>>>
Ones
```

Comment: I need to have the name as a variable.

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.ones([4,4]) )
df.name = 'df'

print df.name
>>>
df

Comment: For posterity, as of v 0.18.1 this does [not survive pickling](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/447#issuecomment-10949838) (for v 0.18.1 use `to_pickle`/ `read_pickle` instead of `save`/`load` if trying to reproduce the GitHub comment).

Comment: A workaround I found is to place your `DataFrame`'s name in the index's name attribute (e.g. `df.index.name = 'Ones'`). This is maintained during pickling.  This only works if your `DataFrame`'s index is not already named something useful...

Comment: FYI, this was found while using `DataFrame`s inside `multiprocessing.Pool()` workers.  The attributes were not maintained during `.map()` because of the pickling it uses.

Comment: This is a poor idea because if you as much as `drop` something, the returned object will no longer have a `name` attribute. It's tempting, but will create inexplicable errors down the line.

Comment: Really veru bad idea. If you call df.name = Ones is the same than df['name] = 'Ones'. it means the valiues for that column will be 'One'. SO it is not a correct answer. You can stor your dataframes within a dictionary and use the key to identify them

Comment: @ajsp You mean if you already have a column named "name", not "Ones".

Comment: @wjandrea He thinks that `df.name = 'Ones'` is the same as `df['name'] = 'Ones'`. But yes you are correct, I had that back to front.

Answer (score 56):

Sometimes `df.name` doesn't work.

you might get an error message:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

try the below function:

```
def get_df_name(df):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name
```

Comment: It will throw ` 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'` when it doesn't assign any name

Comment: Just to make sure people aren't confused: what the snippet here does is to find the dataframe in all currently defined global variables and return its variable name. This is **NOT** guaranteed to work (e.g. your DF is a local variable) and there are no error handling mechanisms in place. You should only use this if you're sure what you're doing!

Comment: chill dude. Its only a suggestion for a solution.
However, I have this situation where this snippet of code is not working.

Answer (score 31):

In many situations, a custom attribute attached to a `pd.DataFrame` object is not necessary. In addition, note that `pandas`-object attributes [may not serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13251056/9209546). So pickling will lose this data.

Instead, consider creating a dictionary with appropriately named keys and access the dataframe via `dfs['some_label']`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

dfs = {'some_label': df}
```

Answer (score 20):

DataFrames don't have names, but you have an (**experimental**) [attribute dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html) you can use. For example:

```
df.attrs['name'] = "My name"   # Can be retrieved later
```

attributes are retained through some operations.

Comment: Using `df.attrs['name']` after pickling works. Great answer.

Comment: Thank you for alerting everyone about this new feature.  The attributes dictionaries in series.attrs and dataframe.attrs both work and can contain as many attributes as one wishes to bind in the attributes dictionary.

Comment: my pleasure. As noted, pandas says this is an “experimental” feature, so hopefully they won't change it too much or remove it.

Answer (score 15):

From [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/dsintro.html#dataframe) what I understand DataFrames are:

> DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects.

And Series are:

> Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc.).

Series have a `name` attribute which can be accessed like so:

```
 In [27]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), name='something')

 In [28]: s
 Out[28]: 
 0    0.541
 1   -1.175
 2    0.129
 3    0.043
 4   -0.429
 Name: something, dtype: float64

 In [29]: s.name
 Out[29]: 'something'
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comments, I think OP was looking for something like:

```
 >>> df = pd.DataFrame(...)
 >>> df.name = 'df' # making a custom attribute that DataFrame doesn't intrinsically have
 >>> print(df.name)
 'df'
```

Comment: i need the name to be a variable somewhat like name=<table name>

Comment: What do you mean variable? Like calling `df` prints the name `"df"` instead of printing the dataframe?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Comment: But how do you want the data frame to be called?

Comment: say the name of the file is apple.csv. I want it to get printed like The file came from apple. --- only that apple has to be dynamic depending on the name of the csv file.

Comment: @leo, any solution to this? did you get the dataframe name without the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a module for feature analysis and I had the same need as yours, as I would like to generate a report with the name of the dataframe being analyzed. To solve this, I used the same solution [presented by @scohe001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425523/8508275), implemented with the inspect library:

```
import inspect

def aux_retrieve_name(var):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]
```

Note the additional `.f_back` term since I intend to call it from another function:

```
def header_generator(df):
    print('--------- Feature Analyzer ----------')
    print('Dataframe name: "{}"'.format(aux_retrieve_name(df)))
    print('Memory usage: {:03.2f} MB'.format(df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2))
    return
```

Running this code with a given dataframe, I get the following output:

```
header_generator(trial_dataframe)
```

> --------- Feature Analyzer ----------
> Dataframe name: "trial_dataframe"
> Memory usage: 63.08 MB

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function:
'df.name = file` : Sixth line in the code below

```
def df_list():
    filename_list = current_stage_files(PATH)
    df_list = []
    for file in filename_list:
        df = pd.read_csv(PATH+file)
        df.name = file
        df_list.append(df)
    return df_list
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the variable name for a DataFrame in Python, you can't do it directly using native Python or pandas attributes. However, you can use a workaround by examining the globals() or locals() dictionaries to match IDs. Here's a function that can find the name of a DataFrame:

```
def find_df_name(df):
   name = [name for name, obj in globals().items() if id(obj) == id(df)]
   return name[0] if name else None
```

usage:

```
df_name = find_df_name(burnishing_defects)
print(df_name)
```