# Create a variable/DataFrame that gets its name from a parameter of a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried searching the forums, but couldn't really find one for the problem I am facing.
I am trying to create a dataframe within a function.
However the name of the dataframe is something I want to dynamically create based on a parameter value that is passed to the function.

Am not sure how I can do this in a quick way.
Can you please advise.

Eg:

```
def Upload(file, ABC):
    df_ABC = pd.read.......
    return df_ABC


def Upload(file, NYK):
    df_NYK = pd.read.......
    return df_NYK
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the name of a Pandas DataFrame \[Python\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe-python)

Comment: So you want to dynamically create variables from these functions?

Comment: @zipa : Yes, the parameter value should be dynamically appended to a variable in order to form a unique variable name/string

Comment: What's wrong with `df.name` attribute? What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to dynamically create based on a parameter value that is passed
>   to the function.

You can use `locals`.

```
locals()['df_'+ ABC] = pd.read....
```

But it's not recommended to do this. Use a *dictionary* instead.

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['df_' + ABC] = pd.read.......
```

When you want to *return* value the *dataframe* just use `bracket` notation.

```
return my_dict['df_' + ABC]
```

Comment: @ Mihai Alexandru-lonut : Can you please share a template how the dictionary can be used for this..

Comment: And how would the return statement look like.
     return df_ ?

Comment: @asimo, `return my_dict['df_' + ABC]`