# Save multiple dataFrames in a loop using to_pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pickle

hi i have 4 pandas dataframe: df1, df2 ,df3, df4.
What i like to do is iterate (using a for loop) the save of this dataframe using `to_pickle`.
what i did is this:

```
out = 'mypath\\myfolder\\'

r = [ orders, adobe, mails , sells]
for i in r:
    i.to_pickle( out +   '\\i.pkl')
```

The command is fine but it does not save every database with his name but overwriting the same databse `i.pkl` (i think because is not correct my code)
It seem it can't rename every database with his name (e.g. for orders inside the for loop **orders** is saved with the name `i.pkl` and so on with the **orders** dataframe involved)
What i expect is to have 4 dataframe saved with the name inserted in the object r (so : orders.pkl, adobe.pkl ,mails.pkl, sells.pkl)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't stringify the variable name (this is not something you generally do), but you can do something simple:

```
import os

out = 'mypath\\myfolder\\'

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 1):
    df.to_pickle(os.path.join(out, f'\\df{i}.pkl')
```

---

If you want to provide custom names for your files, here is my suggestion: use a dictionary.

```
df_map = {'orders': df1, 'adobe': df2, 'mails': df3, 'sells': df4}
for name, df in df_map.items():
    df.to_pickle(os.path.join(out, f'\\{name}.pkl')
```

Comment: thank you, what if my df list would contains different names? (e.g: df_lis=[ orders, adobe, mails , sells] )

Comment: @lucapellerossapelles There is no clean way to do it unless you use a dictionary (see edit).

Comment: This is true, as DataFrames do not have a `name` attribute. You must handle the names on your own. A dictionairy is the right choice here. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe)