# How can I manipulate a DataFrame name within a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I manipulate a DataFrame name within a function so that I can have a new DataFrame with a new name that is derived from the input DataFrame name in return?

let say I have this:

```
def some_func(df):
   # some operations
   return(df_copy)
```

and whatever df I put inside this function it should return the new df as ..._copy, e.g. some_func(my_frame) should return my_frame_copy.

Things that I **considered** are as follows:

1. As in string operations;
   `new_df_name = "{}_copy".format(df)` -- I know this will not work since the df refers to an object but it just helps to explain what I am trying to do.
2. 

```
def date_timer(df):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    dates = df_copy.columns[df_copy.columns.str.contains('date')]
    for i in range(len(dates)):
        df_copy[dates[i]] = pd.to_datetime(df_copy[dates[i]].str.replace('T', ' '), errors='coerce')
    return(df_copy)
```

3. Actually this was the first thing that I tried, If only DataFrame had a "name" attribute which allowed us to manipulate the name but this also not there:

```
df.name
```

Maybe f-string or any kind of string operations could be able to make it happen. if not, it might not be possible to do in python.

I think this might be related to variable name assignment rules in python. And in a sense what I want is reverse engineer that but probably not possible.
Please advice...

Comment: See my answer below @yakbu002 – if it's helpful, accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to access / dynamically set the global/local namespace of a variable from your program.

Unless your data object belongs to a more structured [namespace object](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace), ***I'd discourage you from dynamically setting names with such a method*** since a lot can go wrong, as [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> Changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

---

The `name` attribute of your `df` is not an ideal solution since the state of that attribute will not be set on default. Nor is it particularly common. However, here is a solid [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727549/10521959) which addresses this.

---

You might be better off storing your data objects in a dictionary, using dates or something meaningful as keys. *Example:*

```
my_data = {}

for my_date in dates:
    df_temp = df.copy(deep=True) # deep copy ensures no changes are translated to the parent object
    # Modify your df here (not sure what you are trying to do exactly
    df_temp[my_date] = "foo"
    
    # Now save that df
    my_data[my_date] = df_temp
```

---

Hope this answers your Q. Feel free to clarify in the comments.