# How to use a variable name as string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, attributes

In Python, I've created a bunch of dataframes like so:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
...
df50 = pd.read_csv("50.csv") # import modes may vary based on the csv, no real way to shorten this
```

For every dataframe, I'd like to perform an operation which requires assigning a string as a name. For instance, given an existing database `db`,

```
df1.to_sql("df1", db) # and so on.
```

The dataframes may have a non-sequential name, so I can't do `for i in range(1,51): "df"+str(i)`.

I'm looking for the right way to do this, instead of repeating the line 50 times. My idea was something like

```
for df in [df1, df2... df50]: 
    df.to_sql(df.__name__, db) # but dataframes don't have a __name__
```

1. How do I get the string `"df1"` from the dataframe I've called `df1`?
2. Is there an even nicer way to do all this?

Comment: You could put your dataframes in a container (list / dict) in the first place and loop over it afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Tom Sort of. It does suggest adding a little bit of code when importing them, but I was rather looking for something like this thread that I've just found  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523

It does suggest, though, that what I want is quite cumbersome

Comment: @Zubo as I mentioned in my answer this isn't really something you should be doing

Comment: Objects have no idea what variables haooe. To refer to them and what their names are. That's because *you shouldn't be writing code that requires it*. If you need to associate a string with another object, there are various ways to do that. Variable names are for humans reading source code, they shouldn't contain data

Answer (score 0):

Since the name appears to have been created following a pattern in the first place, just use code to replicate that pattern:

```
for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2... df50]):
    df.to_sql(f'df{i}', db)
```

(Better yet, don't have those variables in the first place; create the list directly.)

> The dataframes may have a non-sequential name, so I can't do for i in range(1,51): "df"+str(i).

Oh. Well in that case, if you want to *associate textual names* with the objects, that don't follow a pattern, that is what a `dict` is for:

```
dfs = {
    "df1": pd.read_csv("1.csv"),
    # whichever other names and values make sense
}
```

which you can iterate over easily:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_sql(name, db)
```

If there is a *logical rule* that relates the input filename to the one that should be used for the `to_sql` call, you can use a dict comprehension to build the dict:

```
dfs = {to_sql_name(csv_name): pd.read_csv(csv_name) for csv_name in ...}
```

Or do the loading and processing in the same loop:

```
for csv_name in ...:
    pd.read_csv(csv_name).to_sql(to_sql_name(csv_name), db)
```