# retrieve the name of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to retrieve the name of my pandas. For instance:

```
A=pd.DataFrame()
print('the name of my pandas is ' + XXX)
```

What should be XXX to get

```
the name of my pandas is A
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: you will find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620134/206413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: if you assign `XXX = A` then it will have different name. But variable's name is not assigned to `DataFrame` (or any other data) and you can't get `A` when you have assigned to `XXX`. And if you put `print( ... + A)` then you already know name and you can put it manually in text `"...is A"`. For me all this is only waste of time.

Comment: Why, exactly, do you want to do this?

Comment: I would to implement a method which takes 2 arguments: a list of pandas and a list of columns (associates to those pandas). Basically this method merge all the pandas columns into a 'master' pandas. I would like to rename the pandas columns using the name of the associate pandas (cause sometimes the columns names  are the same). To do so I need to retrieve the name of the considered pandas. Does it makes sense ?

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this is more of a Python question. But over time I've realized that the simplest way to keep track of names of dataframe (and variables in general) is to just store them in a dictionary.

```
dfs_stored = {}

# do some procedure
for varname in varname_list:
    dfs_stored[varname] = pd.DataFrame(some_data)

dfs_stored['A'] # lookup by name
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is more about python than pandas.
You can see [how to view all defined variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/viewing-all-defined-variables-in-python/) in python on Geeks for Geeks.

This snippet can help you

```py
A=pd.DataFrame()

all_variables = dir()
for name in all_variables:
    if type(eval(name)) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame:
        print('the name of my pandas is ' + name)
```