# Function: make argument executable

Tags: python, function, arguments

So I have the following Code. It should export an excelfile but the naming does not work. Though the contents are alright.
The file is named **"Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column1, Column2]
Index: [].xlsx"**

It should be named testDF.xlsx. Is there an easy solution?

```
import pandas as pd

ExportExcelParam = 1;

testDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column1','Column2'], dtype=object)


def ExcelExportDF(Dataframe, ExportExcelParam):
    if ExportExcelParam == 1: 
        Filename = str(Dataframe) + ".xlsx"
        Dataframe.to_excel(Filename)


ExcelExportDF(testDF, ExportExcelParam)
```

Comment: `Filename = "testDF.xlsx"`? What do you think `str(Dataframe)` returns?

Comment: @Mark You cannot just do `str(Dataframe)` to get the name of the `Dataframe`. You might have to iterate through `globals` to get the name

Comment: You're not wrong in this case. But I'd like the function to name the excelfile after the given Dataframe name. So not static but based on the argument Dataframe.

Comment: An object has absolutely no way to know what name you assigned it. So what part of the dataframe has the name you want?

Comment: Thanks, that makes totally sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `testDF` is not a string, it is just a name of your variable. Now that variable contains a `DataFrame`, so when you use `str()`, it will try to provide a reasonable string that represents the `DataFrame` itself.

An easy solution is to pass the name as string in an additional parameter. Yes, it requires to type the name twice, but it is probable the safest and most straight-forward option, unless you can retrieve the name from somehwere else.

```python
def ExcelExportDF(Dataframe, Filename, ExportExcelParam):
    if ExportExcelParam == 1: 
        Dataframe.to_excel(Filename + ".xlsx")


ExcelExportDF(testDF, 'testDF', ExportExcelParam)
```

**Edit:** Just saw the comments. If you know what you are doing, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620134/12661819) could work.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Pass the object _and_ the string. Otherwise iterating through globals should work!