# pandas: using a list of dfs, perform some action on all dfs and list df names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I made a list of a set of dfs:

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

I want to loop through all the dfs in the list, print the df name, and print the first 2 lines.

In unix it is simple to do what I want:

```
cat dflist | while read i; do echo $i && head -2 $i; done
```

Which returns:

```
US_distribution_of_soybean_aphid_2022.csv
State,Status of Aphis glycines in 2022,Source,
Connecticut,Present,Rutledge (2004),
```

But in pandas,

```
for i in dflist:
    print('i')
    print(i.head(2))
```

returns literal i followed by the desired head(2) results.

```
i

   Year           Analyte            Class  SortOrder  PercentAcresTreated  \
0  1991          Methomyl        carbamate       2840              0.00125   
1  1991  Methyl parathion  organophosphate       2900              0.01000
```

Using:

```
for i in dflist:
    print(i)
```

Prints each df in its entirety.

Very frustrating to a newbie trying to understand the python equivalents of commands I use every day. I'm currently working in a jupyter notebook, if that matters.

Comment: share the actual output and the expected out, that's unclear what you want. Also share how you built `dflist`

Comment: @MichaelS. Yes! That worked, thank you! After doing df.name on each df, when I ran `for i in dflist:
    print(i.name)
    print(i.head(2))` I got the result I was after. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before proceeding, [give these answers a read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe). You can name your dataframes with `df.name` after you create them. Then you can print their names with `print(df.name)`. Just be careful to not have a column named `name`. In reality, you can name `name` anything. `df.dataframe_name` works as well. Just make it unique in that it is not one of your column names:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({"Column":[1,2,3,4,5]})
test.name = "Test"

new_test = pd.DataFrame({"Column":[1,2,3,4,5]})
new_test.name = "New Test"

third_test = pd.DataFrame({"Column":[1,2,3,4,5]})
third_test.name = "Third Test"

last_test = pd.DataFrame({"Column":[1,2,3,4,5]})
last_test.name = "Last Test"
dflist = [test, new_test, third_test, last_test]
for i in dflist:
    print(i.name)
    print(i.head(2))
```

Output:

```
Test
   Column
0       1
1       2
New Test
   Column
0       1
1       2
Third Test
   Column
0       1
1       2
Last Test
   Column
0       1
1       2
```

Comment: You can assign anything in a DataFrame, but if you clash with a useful column or method you will have problems. Rather use `df.attrs` to store metadata. That said, for the use described by OP a simple dictionary seems more appropriate.

Comment: it seems counter to the ethos of coding that only ONE answer can be accepted when of course there are many equally valid ways to solve a problem...

Answer (score 1):

You must use a container. Accessing names programmatically is highly discouraged.

For instance, a list:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in dfs:
    print(df.head())
```

Or, if you need "names", a dictionary:

```
dfs = {'start': df1, 'middle': df2, 'end': df3}

for name, df in dfs.items():
    print(name)
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: are you saying this method is safer than doing df.names? Can you explain why?

Comment: @Sara I briefly mentioned it in my comment, this is unsafe as it can conflict with the DataFrame indexing. Try `df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [1,2,3]}) ; df.name = 'abc' ; print(df)`. You just corrupted the data and `df.name` won't even return a string. Even if it doesn't conflict it can be lost on certain operations that return a copy of the DataFrame. There is a [`attrs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html) dictionary to save metadata but the feature is experimental and might change in the future ;)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to lay that out. I'm trying to keep an eye on what's "under the hood" as I start using python and appreciate your explanation.