# How to save a dataframe with the same dataframe name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, export-to-csv

How to save a dataframe with the same dataframe name in python?
In order to do that I need to extract the name of the dataframe and use it as a text to save to csv file. like dataframe.to_csv('name of the dataframe'+'.csv). My question is how to extract the name of the dataframe.
Example:
I have a dataframe that is randomly generated as XX_20135.
XX_20135.to_csv('XX_20135.csv') so in the output I will have the csv name as XX_20135. I don't know the name of the df in advance as it is generated randomly.

Comment: have a look here. It is not safe to work and not recommended, but that's what you are searching for right? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50620134/15521392

Comment: Yes, sounds like in the very last reply would to the job. Thank you! 


def aux_retrieve_name(var):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]


def header_generator(df):
    print('--------- Feature Analyzer ----------')
    print('Dataframe name: "{}"'.format(aux_retrieve_name(df)))
    print('Memory usage: {:03.2f} MB'.format(df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2))
    return

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the dataframe name the same as variable name? If so, the variable name is fixed, isn't it? If it is fixed, you know it when running the code.

Comment: Yes, when the dataframe is randomly generated, I would know the name but still I need a command to extract the name of the dataframe as a string to be able to save the file with the same name. The question is how to extract the dataframe name as a string. Sound simple but did not find a way in my search.