# I wish to print a pandas dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, printing

Please be patient I am new to Python and Pandas.
I have a lot of pandas dataframe, but some are duplicates. So I wrote a function that check if 2 dataframes are equal, if they are 1 will be deleted:

```py
def check_eq(df1, df2):
    if df1.equals(df2):
        del[df2]
        print( "Deleted %s" (df_name) )
```

The function works, but I wish to know how to have the variable "df_name" as string with the name of the dataframe.
I don't understand, the parameters df1 and df2 are dataframe objects how I can get their name at run-time if I wish to print it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to use is an f-string.

```
def check_eq(df1, df2):
    if df1.equals(df2):
        del[df2]
        print(f"Deleted {df2.name}")
```

I'm not certain whether you can call this print method, though. Since you deleted the dataframe right before you call its name attribute. So df2 is unbound.

Instead try this:

```
def check_eq(df1, df2):
    if df1.equals(df2):
        print(f"Deleted {df2.name}")
        del df2
```

Now, do note that your usage of 'del' is also not correct. I assume you want to delete the second dataframe in your code. However, you only delete it inside the scope of the check_eq method. You should familiarize yourself with the scope concept first. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

The code I used:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1.name='dataframe1'
df2.name='dataframe2'

def check_eq(df1, df2):
    if df1.equals(df2):
        print(f"Deleted {df2.name}")
```