# Pandas dataframe: How to get the name displayed as a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to find a way to print the name of a pandas dataframe.
I already tried a solution from stackoverflow and it doesn't work:

```
print(my_dataframe.attrs('name'))
```

I also tried:

```
print(my_dataframe.info)
```

It's not included in the info.

I tried to inspect the DF in order to see if it was saved in some property or function, but I found nothing about it in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

I am currently working with Pandas 2.0.3

Could someone help me to convert the dataframe name to a string?

Comment: What makes you think a DataFrame has a name?

Comment: Related and popular question [Get the name of a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31727333/12846804) but keep in mind that a dataframe has no name

Comment: You can call it identifier, maybe the term was not the correct one. But is a dataframe object and it is identify, in my case, with my_dataframe.

Comment: Regarding the closure as duplicate of [Getting the name of a variable as a string](/q/18425225/4518341), see [kindall's answer](/a/18425275/4518341) for why this isn't possible in general, and [scohe001's answer](/a/18425523/4518341) for the equivalent of Jason's answer here ([link for reference](/a/77834178/4518341)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

You can use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and create a function to return str.

Code:

```
import inspect
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd


def variable_name_to_string(variable: Any) -> str:
    return [k for k, v in inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items() if v is variable][0]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"spam": [1, 2], "ham": [3, 4]})
df_name = variable_name_to_string(variable=df)
print(type(df_name))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: its just a list comp that goes through dict_items from the inspect obj to find your variable